# Android OnTouch won't execute return command

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, ontouchlistener

this problem is driving me up the wall. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure it out.

I have a static OnTouchListener which I attach to the TextView of a number of identical compound view objects contained within a linearlayout. This listener is in a helper class.

```
    public static View.OnTouchListener getValueTouchListener() {
    return new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private int lastY;
        private int lastX;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            TextView view = (TextView)v;
            int action = event.getActionMasked();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cog_pressed);
                    lastY = (int)event.getY();
                    lastX = (int)event.getX();
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    //calc size of movement
                    int deltaY = lastY - (int)event.getY();
                    int deltaX = lastX - (int)event.getX();
                    // pass gesture up to parent if it's a big x movement - assumes user wishes to scroll parent
                    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > TOUCH_SLOP *2) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    lastX = (int)event.getX();
                    //process movement if larger than a touch slop
                    if (StrictMath.abs(deltaY) > TOUCH_SLOP) {
                        // reset last touch position
                        lastY = (int)event.getY();
                        //get direction of movement
                        int dir = (deltaY < 0)? -1 : 1;
                        //change index if within min and max limits
                        int min = (view.getTag() == Chainring.KEY)? Chainring.MIN_COG : Sprocket.MIN_COG;
                        int max = (view.getTag() == Chainring.KEY)? Chainring.MAX_COG : Sprocket.MAX_COG;
                        int value = Integer.valueOf(view.getText().toString());
                        if ((dir == -1 && value > min) || (dir == 1 && value < max)) {
                            value = value + dir;
                            view.setText(String.valueOf(value));
                            view.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cog_unpressed);
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cog_unpressed);
                    return false;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I hook up this listener to my TextView in a class that extends linear layout

```
        mValueTextView.setOnTouchListener(CogPickerHelper.getValueTouchListener());
```

My problem is the method doesn't seem to execute the return command in the ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_UP and ACTION-MOVE cases. For example, with an ACTION_DOWN, the code executes as far as the return command but then steps directly to the default case and returns false - even though Logcat still reports the action as being ACTION-DOWN.

If I try to set a breakpoint on the return commands, IntelliJ says: "No executable code found at line X in class com.amb.GearBuddyV2.views.CogPickerHelper$2"

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be working fine, the **OnTouch** return value is being returned correctly.

And yes, adding a break at a return statement will lead the debugger to complain about missing executable code.

Comment: I think that's my point, the code isn't working. I cannot return true on the first three cases, so I'm basically unable to consume the event... and, logically, I don't understand how the switch can go to two cases in the same pass when each case ends with a return statement. Also, I am able to add a breakpoint on the return statement in the ACTION_CANCEL case which, annoyingly, will return the value and allow me to consume the event.

Comment: The debugging seems to absurdly lead you to two different cases, probably because of switch code optimisation done by the compiler, and the debugger can't match it very well to the actual source. Have you tried using a boolean variable to keep the return value first, instead of returning it immediately? The debugger should let you step through that simple variable assignment and show you what exactly is being assigned for return.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, kheld. I created a boolean and then ended each case with a break command ...  and it does indeed work as you'd expect. I'll go with that plan - it's just a shame I can't understand why one works and the other doesn't.